# Rename mail account?

Tags: ipad, email

I hope this is not too obvious, but I would like to know if this is possible.  I made an email account without renaming it.  So it has the boring name Exchange.  How can I rename this email account on my iPad without deleting and re adding it?  I would rather not type all that info in again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **Mail, Contacts, Calendars** > Tap your Exchange account (for you, it will likely say **Exchange**) > Tap on your exchange email address (i.e. daniel@example.com) > scroll down to **Description** (past Username and Password), then enter the new name in there.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully changed the name others see when I email them (from my iPad Air 2) by putting the name I want them to see into **Contacts** and making sure to give that name the email address I want it to have.  I don't understand why it works but it does!

This may only work on the iPad (possibly just the iPad Air 2), so if you want to change your 'from name' on other devices i.e. your main computer, you'll have to do whatever it takes on those devices.